# Report on task assigned to me

Tags: reporting, tasks, activities

Is it possible to run a report with the parameters that a Task was created by X and assigned to Y?

I created and tested on Activities. I can view records that I created using "My Activities" filter

Comment: did your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can apply filter on `cretedById` and `ownerId`. And change both parameters as per your requirment